# Is there a way to return html in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

i've been using vue for this project. I want to structure the app the best of my ability.
So i want to make use of classes. but this is the problem i'm facing.

my code now:

```js
// models/page.js
export default class Page {
    static createPage() {
        return (
            <p>hey</p>
        )
    }
}

// pages/index.vue
// I made $page work as a global vue prototype. this works and gives not problem
<template>
  <div v-html="this.$page.createPage()"/>
</template>
```

but this gives the following error

[image]

I know in php u can use

```js
function test() {
    return <<<EOT
        <html>
            <body><h1>HELLO</h1></body>
        </html>
    EOT;
 }
```

But is there any way this works in js?

Comment: Put your `<p>hey</p>` between quotes or ticks, because it isn't a string right now.

Comment: You can return HTML in a string, either using a regular string, or a template string.

Comment: are you trying to emulate react.js behavior?, because this way to populate html content isn't recommended thinking about xss atacks

Comment: yes i wanted to do it like react. but i can't do it now :(

Comment: You should read about jsx

Answer (score 1):

You have to just put you html in quotes like:

```
export default class Page {
    static createPage() {
        return (
          `<p>hey</p>
           <p>hey</p>
           <p>hey</p>
           <p>hey</p>
          `
        )
    }
}
```

`v-html` will parse it as html.

Comment: yes, sorry i forgot to mension, but thats not verry great to do.. if i put more html in the page then its a little bit messy. and i want to clearify the code.

Comment: So you can use ES6 templet String it will work for multiline.

Comment: Answer Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class Page {
    static createPage() {
        return (
            "<p>hey</p>"
        )
    }
}
```

This should work perfectly fine. It will append the HTML string in the desired place.

Comment: yes, sorry i forgot to mension, but thats not verry great to do.. if i put more html in the page then its a little bit messy. and i want to clearify the code.